# Linux alternative to Windows Task Scheduler or another way of doing it

Tags: startup, task-management

Does Linux have an alternative to Windows Task Scheduler, another way like a script or an inbuilt function?

Comment: Our version existed way before Windows Task Scheduler ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cron` is the Linux command-line scheduler.  Use `crontab -e` to create (or edit) your cron jobs.

See [Cron HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) and  [crontab (5)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5) for details.

Comment: ...or, if your machine isn't up 24/7, look into anacron as @Volodya suggests.

Answer (score 6):

## [Scheduled tasks](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-schedule/)

[image: Install via the software center]

It is the Task Scheduler in Gnome.

In other way it is a **GUI for Cron**.

Can be installed with **Software Center**.

If use Terminal for installation:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
```

[image]

Comment: Does it require Gnome, or will it work in KDE/X etc?

Comment: It does work in cinnomon desktop and gnome. Doesn't know about KDE

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for anacron function.

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_anacron.htm

Answer (score 2):

cron jobs

how to do it can be found in the link [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)